# rbind nested list of dataframes in one dataframe

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes and those dataframes have different number of columns. I need to rbind all thoese dataframes such that the unmatched columns have NAs in them. An exemplar list (lets call it output_list) looks as below:
Output_list:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "a"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "b"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "a" "b"
```

where "a", "b" and ""a" "b"" are all dataframes. Class(output_list[[1]]) is a list, class(output_list[[1]][[1]]) is a dataframe. Similarly, class(output_list[[2]]) is a list but class(output_list[[2]][[1]]) is a dataframe. Thus, its a nested list with many dataframes. I need to rbind these dataframes in one large frame such that the unmatched columns have NAs in them. I tried rbindlist(output_list, fill = TRUE, use.names =TRUE), but it says: 
"Error in rbindlist(output_list, fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE) : fill=TRUE, but names of input list at position 1 is NULL. All items of input list must have names set when fill=TRUE."
How can I bind them in my desired way? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: you might need to `unlist(output_list, recursive=FALSE)` before `rbindlist`

Comment: Superb!!!! Thanks a lot @ chinsoon12